# No qTranslate translation despite language being set

Tags: wordpress, qtranslate

I'm working with installing the qTranslate multi-language plugin on a WordPress site. The site has a custom plugin from before which complicates things. This question concerns some cases where qTranslate fails to translate Gettext marked strings (`_e`, etc). In these cases, I can verify the qTranslate language and WordPress locale correctly, as near as the line before the Gettext calls, like so:

```
<pre>lang: <?php echo qtrans_getLanguage(); ?></pre>
<p class="message"><?php _e('Cart is empty.', 'myplugin'); ?></p>
```

The string will be output in the language set to default in qTranslate, regardless of the current language. So here's a typical output where Swedish is the default language:

> `lang: en`
>
> Varukorgen är tom.

I understand that you can't see from this summary exactly what is wrong. But can you help me by suggesting what could be possible causes for this behaviour?

Hint: Ajax might be involved, but honestly I'm a bit confused to see if that's really true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `load_plugin_textdomain` call should be inside an init function, so instead of

```
load_plugin_textdomain('myplugin', false, dirname(plugin_basename(__FILE__))
    . '/languages/');
```

I did

```
function myplugin_init() {
    load_plugin_textdomain('myplugin', false, dirname(plugin_basename(__FILE__))
        . '/languages/');
}
add_action( 'init', 'myplugin_init' );
```

and it worked.